# How to Extend the Scope of This

Tags: javascript, object, this

How can I extend the scope of this so that the below works? I've tried using the .bind() function but I can't seem to get anything to work.

```
var myObj = {
   test: "Hello",
   test2: " World",
   run: {
      all: function() {
         return this.test + this.test2;
      },
      part: function() {
         return this.test2;
      }
   }
}
console.log(myObj.run.all())
// => "Hello World"
console.log(myObj.run.part())
// => " World"
```

Comment: You have to understand: `this` in your functions is the current object, which is what you affect to `run`, and not the super-object. In run(and `this` btw), there are only `all()` and `part()`, there is no `test` and `test2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same issue recently.
I solved by using a function

```
var myObj = function(){
   var self = this;
   this.test = "Hello";
   this.test2 = " World";
   this.run = {
      all: function() {
         return self.test + self.test2;
      },
      part: function() {
         return self.test2;
      }
   }
}
console.log(myObj.run.all())
// => "Hello World"
console.log(myObj.run.part())
// => " World"
```

I also found out the **bind** does the job!

```
var myObj = {
   test: "Hello",
   test2: " World",
   run: {
      all: function() {
         return this.test + this.test2;
      },
      part: function() {
         return this.test2;
      }
   }
};

console.log( myObj.run.all.bind(myObj)() );
// => "Hello World"
console.log( myObj.run.part.bind(myObj)() );
// => "World"
```

Working fiddle ==> https://jsfiddle.net/sn5w7872/

Answer (score 1):

The functions `all` and `part` are members of the object `run` and `run` does not have the values `test` and `test2`. They're member objects of `myObj`.

You can replace the `this` keyword with `myObj`.

```js
var myObj = {
   test: "Hello",
   test2: " World",
   run: {
      all: function() {
         return myObj.test + myObj.test2;
      },
      part: function() {
         return myObj.test2;
      }
   }
}
console.log(myObj.run.all())
console.log(myObj.run.part())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

The `apply()` method calls a function with a given `this` value, and arguments provided as an array

```js
var myObj = {
   test: "Hello",
   test2: " World",
   run: {
      all: function() {
         return this.test + this.test2;
      },
      part: function() {
         return this.test2;
      }
   }
}
console.log(myObj.run.all.apply(myObj,[]));
// => "Hello World"
console.log(myObj.run.part.apply(myObj,[]));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use ES6 classes and arrow functions.

```
class myObj {
    constructor() {
        this.test = "Hello";
        this.test2 = " World";
        this.run = {
            all: () => this.test + this.test2,
            part: () => this.test2
        }
    }
}

var obj = new myObj();
console.log(obj.run.all())
// => "Hello World"
console.log(obj.run.part())
// => " World"
```

Here is the working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/sgsvenkatesh/vn9b1f95/